# check if substring exist in string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check if a sub string is included in a string, but the sub string contains a number, this number can change. I used RegExp but it's not working

```
let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint";

url.includes('/issue/board/537/sprint'); // true
```

the value 537 can change

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');

url.includes('/issue/board/' + reg  +'/sprint'); // false
```

Comment: You need to use one of the regex methods like `test` or `match` to "use regex." Currently you're just concatenating the regex into a string and use regular substring search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const reg = new RegExp('/issue/board/[0-9]+/sprint');

const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint";
const matches = url.match(reg);

console.log(matches ? true: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you use Regex.

Create an expression:

```
const reg = new RegExp('/issue/board/[0-9]+/sprint');
```

And test it against your url:

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint";
const matches = url.test(reg); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var reg = new RegExp('/issue/board/[0-9]+/sprint')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const condition = new RegExp('\/issue\/board\/[0-9]+\/sprint').test('http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = new RegExp('\/board\/(.*?)\/sprint');

const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint';
const test = regex.test(url);
const matches = regex.exec(url);

console.log(test); // true
console.log(matches[1]); //537
```

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is just to use indexOf. Like so

```
let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/issue/board/537/sprint",
    match = '/issue/board/537/sprint';

if (url.indexOf(match) !== -1) {
  // true
} else {
  // false 
}
```

The indexOf a string that isn't contained in the string you're checking will always be -1